# Django URL redirection issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

Hi guys I am trying to use a django App that I found called django-invitations (https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations)

It use an mail invitation to create a user. 
I created a registration app called registration using a view:

```
def registerCandidate(request):
registered  = False
if request.method == "POST":
    Candidate_form = CandidateForm(data=request.POST)

    if Candidate_form.is_valid():
        user = Candidate_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.is_candidate = True
        user.save()
        registered = True
    else:
        print("Error!")
else:
    Candidate_form = CandidateForm()
return render(request,'Candidate_form_registration.html',
                        {'Candidate_form':Candidate_form,
                         'registered':registered})
```

and an url.py

```
url(r'^candidate_register/$', views.registerCandidate, name='Candidate_register')
```

The thing isI tried to configure like the documentation said in my setting.py 
    INVITATIONS_SIGNUP_REDIRECT = 'registration:registerCandidate'

But I cannot manage to use the right redirection to work could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs claim you must provide "URL name of your signup URL."

So you probably need to use the **named url**, e.g `registration:Candidate_register` or maybe just `Candidate_register`